# Object 'Kind' is missing error while running skaffold dev command

Tags: devops, stdin, missing-data, skaffold, kind

after running skaffold dev command this error i am getting, i am using docker desktop in windos and running this command in linux enviorment wsl subsystem docker and kubernents are working fine i checked everything but not able to detected why this error and how to solve it ?

[cluster is not creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXhVH.png) [but image is generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUtI6.png)  
anyone can help to solve it i am trying from many days .

```
 Obj - error when deleting "STDIN": resource name may not be empty
 - error when deleting "STDIN": resource name may not be empty
 - [unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"labels":{"app":"postgres","type":"local"},"name":"postgres-pv-volume"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"],"capacity":{"storage":"5Gi"},"hostPath":{"path":"/mnt/data2"},"storageClassName":"manual"}}', unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"labels":{"app":"postgres"},"name":"postgres-pv-claim"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"5Gi"}},"storageClassName":"manual"}}']
Cleaning up resources encountered an error, will continue to clean up other resources.


waiting for deletion: running [kubectl --context docker-desktop get -f - --ignore-not-found -ojson]
 - stdout: "{\n    \"apiVersion\": \"v1\",\n    \"items\": [\n        {\n            \"kind\": \"PersistentVolume\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"kind\": \"PersistentVolumeClaim\",\n            \"metadata\": {\n                \"namespace\": \"default\"\n            }\n        }\n    ],\n    \"kind\": \"List\",\n    \"metadata\": {\n        \"resourceVersion\": \"\"\n    }\n}\n"
 - stderr: "unable to decode \"STDIN\": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"postgres\",\"type\":\"local\"},\"name\":\"postgres-pv-volume\"},\"spec\":{\"accessModes\":[\"ReadWriteMany\"],\"capacity\":{\"storage\":\"5Gi\"},\"hostPath\":{\"path\":\"/mnt/data2\"},\"storageClassName\":\"manual\"}}'\nunable to decode \"STDIN\": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"postgres\"},\"name\":\"postgres-pv-claim\"},\"spec\":{\"accessModes\":[\"ReadWriteMany\"],\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"storage\":\"5Gi\"}},\"storageClassName\":\"manual\"}}'\n"
 - cause: exit status 1
```

i am expecting anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong so that i can run skaffold dev command